# Customize TableViewCell with swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I am trying to add subtitle to cells in a table view. I am trying this code but the subtitle is not showing.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("topCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text=listPerson[indexPath.row].name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text="test"
        var personImage=UIImage(named: listPerson[indexPath.row].country)
        cell.imageView?.image=personImage

        return cell
    }
```

I also want to know if it's possible to add another image in the right of the cell.

Comment: This should be possible. You need to make sure that the cell inside the storyboard has the identifier "topCell" for this to work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the text in `detailTextLabel` you have to set the style of the cell in the Attributes Inspector of Interface Builder (<kbd>⌥⌘4</kbd>)to `Subtitle`.

To add a custom image on the right edge you can create the `UIImageView` instance programmatically and add it as subview to the accessory view.

However it might be more suitable to use a custom cell class providing an outlet.

Comment: Thanks @vandian for the response. I have a similar issue. I understand that setting it to `Subtitle` in Interface Builder resolves the issue. But I am trying the whole UI programmatically and is there a way to set the subtitle via code?

Thanks